# Search a string for certain amount of spaces

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula which allows me to search a certain number of " " starting from the end of the text (RIGHT) in a text string in cell A, and then it looks what is on the RIGHT of the text string and search for that bit of text for exact match against a text range in another column text column B.

If exact match is found it should pick what is in corresponding column C and return that value. If more then one match is found in column B then an ERROR should be given.

I have following bit of code which looks at the 3rd space but doesn't return all of the text on the RIGHT hand side

```
=RIGHT(B8,SEARCH(" ",B8,SEARCH(" ",B8,SEARCH(" ",B8)+1)+1)-1)
```

and I still require the compare text formula to cell B and C.

Comment: Can you give a few example strings together with your desired results?

Comment: like if I have "High Road Flats 1-13 Hart House" and I look for the 3rd space and ask for everything on the right I probebly will get art house whener I am looking for 1-13 Hart House, then I want this to be compared against a text array in column B and if a match is foound then the corosponding value in column C should be returned

Answer (score 0):

Try:

=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B8," ",REPT(" ",777)),2331))

though I'm not at all clear about the other parts to your question. Perhaps you could give some examples?

Regards

Comment: once I have got the part of address from column A, I have list of addresses in column B in text format, which I want this addess "1-13 hart House" to be matched against. If the exact match is found a post code which will be in colum C for this particular address and that is what I am looking for

Comment: Dear All,

Thank yo so much for that, this have answered the first part of my question. The second part is that I have to compare thi value with the array of text in another column ie. column D for exact match and if a match is found I want the value against that match in colum E to be returned to me .. Hope this make sense.

so first part picks up address 123 cherley close, looks through column D for a exact match and found cherley close and looks for the value opposite in column E "IG3 9RJ" and gives me that value

Hope this is more clear.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,RIGHT(A8,LEN(A8)-FIND(" ",A8,FIND(" ",A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1)+1)))>1,"ERROR",VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A8,LEN(A8)-FIND(" ",A8,FIND(" ",A8,FIND(" ",A8)+1)+1)),B:C,2,0))
```

and adjust the cell references if required.